# How to avoid the 'not properly formatted as code' alert

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I've been trying for many hours to post a question in Mathematica Stack Exchange and I always get the following warning

[image]

I've done the indentation but did not work (though in the preview looks perfectly fine). I also pressed the code toolbar button and tried to use ``` and ' instead of indenting but did not work either.

How can I fix the problem? I am sure it has to be a really basic mistake of mine.

**Here's the question I want to post:**

I want to compute the Christoffel-symbol for a given metric. I am using the code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/218424/difficulties-on-mathematica-code-to-solve-christoffel-symbols-of-a-particular-me?rq=1), but I am missing something.

The Chrisfoffel-symbol formula is

$$
\Gamma^{\mu}*{\phantom{\mu}\nu\sigma}=\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\alpha}\left{\frac{\partial g*{\alpha\nu}}
{\partial x^{\sigma}}+\frac{\partial g_{\alpha\sigma}}{\partial x^{\nu}}-\frac{\partial
g_{\nu\sigma}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\right}\quad
$$

The metric is given to be

$$
g_{\mu \nu} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \
0 & r^2+b^2 & 0 & 0 \
0 & 0 & (r^2+b^2)\sin^2(\theta) & 0 \
0 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The provided solution is:

$$
\Gamma^{1}*{22}=-r
$$
$$
\Gamma^{1}*{33}=-r\sin^2(\theta)
$$
$$
\Gamma^{2}*{21}=\frac{r}{b^2+r^2}
$$
$$
\Gamma^{2}*{33}=-\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)
$$
$$
\Gamma^{3}*{31}=\frac{r}{b^2+r^2}
$$
$$
\Gamma^{3}*{32}=\cot(\theta)
$$

The code I'm using is

```
    Clear [coord, metric, inversemetric, affine] 

    n = 4; coord = {t, x, y,z}; 

    metric = { {1,0,0,0}, {0,r^2+b^2,0,0}, {0,0,(r^2+b^2)Sin[\[Theta]]^2,0}, {0,0,0,-1}}; 

    inversemetric = Simplify[Inverse[metric]]; 

    affine := affine = Simplify[ Table[(1/2)* Sum[inversemetric[[i, s]]*(D[metric[[s, j]],                     
    coord[[k]]] + 
    D[metric[[s, k]], coord[[j]]] - D[metric[[j, k]], coord[[s]]]), {s, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n},     
    {k, 1, n}]]; 

    listaffine := Table[If[UnsameQ[affine[[i, j, k]], 0], {ToString[\[CapitalGamma][i - 1, j - 1, k 
    -1]], affine[[i, j, k]]}], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}, {k, 1, j}];

    TableForm[Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 2], TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

I am struggling now in how to call out the specific Christoffel symbols correctly. What I do is

```
    affine[[3,3,2]]
```

But I get zero instead of $\cot(\theta)$; the same happens to me with other non-zero terms.

What am I missing? Besides, I'd like to learn how could I display the answer once I know how to actually get it.

Comment: It seems that the MathJax markup at the top is what's triggering the filter.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog why is MathJax code preventing me from posting the question? How should I modify it so that the system allows me to post?

Comment: Btw the linked questions are not helpful to solve my problem (I checked them before posting here).

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog I finally got it posted! :) https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/224280/computing-christoffel-symbols-of-the-second-kind it was about using single $ instead of $$

Comment: @JD_PM Please feel free to add your solution as an answer.

Comment: @JD_PM, `... it was about using single $ instead of $$.` - Most sites (that allow MathJax) accept both single or double **$** depending on whether you are inlining your math or not; a few sites require a backslash delimiter (because most frequently users on ***that*** particular site use a single dollar sign for dollars, leading to followup questions, edits and complaints). Each site's Meta should mention both their MathJax and any other special markup allowed there, and the syntax for its usage.

Comment: @Rob better yet have it on the ask page.

Comment: @Luuklag, [the link is on the Ask Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAsfY.jpg), it leads to the [Editing Help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help), which is edited to point to the Meta's URL containing the 10 minutes worth of reading; which takes weeks / months for people to learn - unless no one took the time to do their part.

Answer (score 2):

The issue was not indenting the code itself (which means that the alert was misleading) but using $$ instead of $